# Using Dropbox, or any third party, framework in Swift class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, dropbox-api

I'm trying to write a swift class that uses the Dropbox Sync API, but can't get swift to see the framework. The objective C in my project can use the Dropbox framework successfully. I have a bridging header that seems to be properly set up in the project settings and references `<Dropbox/Dropbox.h>`. But in my swift file it is as if I have done nothing.

This objective C code in my project works and is what I am trying to replicate in Swift:

```
#import <Dropbox/Dropbox.h>

...

if ([DBAccountManager sharedManager].linkedAccount == nil) {
    [[DBAccountManager sharedManager] linkFromController:self];
    [[DBAccountManager sharedManager] addObserver:self block:^(DBAccount *account) {
        DBFilesystem *fileSystem = [[DBFilesystem alloc] initWithAccount:account];
        [DBFilesystem setSharedFilesystem:fileSystem];
    }];
```

As I said, I have `<Dropbox/Dropbox.h>` in the bridging header that Xcode automatically created for me. However this swift code fails to compile with the error 'Use of unresolved identifier 'DBAccountManager''

```
import UIKit

class PiecesListTableViewController : UITableViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        // This fails with unresolved identifier 'DBAccountManager'
        let accountManager = DBAccountManager.sharedManager

        // As does this
        let accountManagerNew = DBAccountManager(appKey:"", secret:"")
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on how to get my swift code to be able to see the Dropbox framework?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to solve this. Instead I worked around it by abstracting all use of the Dropbox framework into objective C classes and using those in my swift code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the way to do it:

1. Create a dummy `.m` file so that XCode will ask you to create a bridging header, then delete the `.m`
2. Under project **Build settings**, add *DropboxSDK.framework* under **Link Binary with Libraries**
3. Open the `bridging-header` file and write in it `#import <DropboxSDK/DropboxSDK.h>`

XCode won't compile your code, and SourceKit Service will likely crash every time you'll open up a Swift file.

[image]

That's because of two errors in the Dropbox SDK (at least for a Swift environment):

1. Open the *DropboxSDK.framework* you linked before in **Finder**, then navigate to `Headers` folder
2. Open the file `DBQuota.h` and add `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` before `@interface`
3. Open the file `DBSession+iOS.h` and add `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` before `@interface`

**Now you can use Dropbox SDK classes in your Swift files.**

This will save you from creating an Objective-C wrapper on each class.